# Вызов функции по истечении времени, таймер в С++

Tags: c++, таймер

Обгуглил все что можно, но нужное для меня решение так и не нашел. Значит, вот что требуется: запускается программа, в некоторый момент она ждет нажатия любой клавиши для продолжения. После нажатия должен пойти отсчет времени, по истечении которого вызывается функция. Либо если по другому, то по истечении времени должен прекратить работу цикл. Как это реализовать?

P.S. Немного перефразирую вопрос: мне нужно, чтобы, например, за 30 секунд студент проходил тест, если время выйдет, то высвечивается сообщение "Время вышло", и заканчивается цикл с вопросами, он уже не может отвечать. При этом у меня вроде получилось сделать через многопоточность завершение теста по истечению таймера, но возник другой вопрос - как извлечь из функции-цикла с вопросами кол-во верных ответов, если она завершилась досрочно (когда вышло время таймера)?.

Comment: [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)